# Can Lilypond typeset French beaming?

Tags: lilypond, engraving, beaming

Consider following example:

[image: four semiquavers beamed together]

```
{
    g'16 d'' e'' d''
}
```

Is there a way to obtain the so-called French beaming? Here, vertical stems are not shown in between the beams (examples from [here](https://forums.steinberg.net/t/ligature-in-french-style/725146)).

[image: semiquavers beamed with French beaming (stems do not protrude into beams)]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I'm not sure why I can’t find it in the documentation, but French beaming is relatively trivial to achieve with LilyPond:

```
{
    \override Stem.french-beaming = ##t
    g'16 d'' e'' d''
}
```

[image: four semiquavers with French beaming]